# Почему между картинками расстояние разное?

Tags: html, css

[image: Почему между картинками расстояние разное?]

```css
.block_hair {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #fbf6f0;
}

.block_hair-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block_hair-window {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block_hair-img {
  width: 340px;
  height: 260px;
}

.block_hair-link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #abc0db;
}
```

```html
<section class="block_hair">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="block_hair-items">
              <div class="block_hair-window">
                <img
                  class="block_hair-img"
                  src="images/image-hair1.jpeg"
                  alt=""
                />
                <a href="" class="block_hair-link">High Performance</a>
                <p class="block_hair-text"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="block_hair-window">
                <img
                  class="block_hair-img"
                  src="images/image-hair2.jpeg"
                  alt=""
                />
                <a href="" class="block_hair-link">Super Clean</a>
                <p class="block_hair-text"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="block_hair-window">
                <img
                  class="block_hair-img"
                  src="images/image-hair3.jpeg"
                  alt=""
                />
                <a href="" class="block_hair-link">Made for Eco-Optimists</a>
                <p class="block_hair-text"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Запустил ваш код - расстояния между картинками нет вообще. Похоже вы не все стили приложили, которые отвечают за это

Comment: Если навскидку, то как минимум можно добавить `flex-basis: 33.33%;` классу `.block_hair-window`

Answer (score 0):

В условиях когда Вы привели не всю верстку html-страницы трудно судить в чем именно дело, но по имеющемуся куску можно судить о следующем, при такой верстке у вас все `<a href` идущие после `<img/>` будут, при наличии свободного места справа "прилипать" к правому краю `<img/>` и тем самым отодвигать `<img/>` влево. Это хорошо заметно при больших разрешениях экрана. Добавьте явный перенос строки `<br/>` после `<img/>`.